# unexpected end of file (script doesnt work)

Tags: bash

when i'm writing that script and tyring to run it it says :
unexpected end of file about [[line == temp ]] .
i'm trying to read lines from file and delete all repetitions in the file.
cleanFiles delete all the empty lines

```
while read line; do
    while read temp; do
        if[[ line == temp ]]; then
            temp=" ";
        fi
    done
./cleanLines $1
done
```

Comment: You might be able to use this: `cat file_name.txt | uniq >> output.txt`

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @ryekayo: More simply: `uniq file_name.txt >> output.txt`. Omer: Do you want to remove only adjacent repetitions, or all repetitions? If the input consists of 3 lines `foo`, `bar`, and `foo` in that order, do you want to print both occurrences of `foo`?

Comment: @ryekayo, `uniq <file_name.txt >>output.txt` is a much more efficient way of writing that. A pipeline from `cat` is much slower to read from than a direct file descriptor. I'd also consider `sort -u` rather than `uniq`, which only works if input is pre-sorted.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a space after the `if`.

```
if[[ line == temp ]]; then   # wrong
if [[ line == temp ]]; then  # still wrong, but see below
```

But that still compares the literal strings `line` and `temp`. If you want to refer to the values of the variables, you need `$` signs:

```
if [[ "$line" == "$temp" ]]; then # right
```

The double quotes on `"$temp"` prevent it from being interpreted as a glob pattern; I also added double quotes on `"$line"` just for symmetry.

Comment: @Jahid: Good catch, fixed.

Comment: Hey guys , thanks for the help. I'll check if it work and let you know .

Comment: @OmerEliyahu: You're welcome. (BTW, the usual way to express thanks is to upvote and/or accept an answer -- *if* you think it's a good answer or it solves your problem, respectively.)

Comment: @Jahid: Unless the script is executed with its input directed from a file.

Comment: Also, you should double-quote at least the right side of the comparison (that is, `[[ $line == "$temp" ]]`), or else it'll be compared as a glob pattern rather than as a literal string.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Fixed. (I find it a bit annoying that `==` does a pattern match rather than an equality comparison. There ought to be a separate syntax for that, though `=~` isn't available, since it treats the RHS as a regex.)

Comment: I agree, but since I habitually double-quote all variable references (even in `[[ ]]`) unless there's a specific reason not to, it doesn't bug me that much. And the ability to partially quote the match string is useful -- for instance, `[[ "$string1" == *"$string2"* ]]` will treat the contents of `$string2` literally, but treat the `*`s as wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys another question that I got - I am new in bash and I need to merge few files , remove repetitions and sort them alphabetically. I am not allowed to use temporary files. CleanLines script doing echo . I can redirect it to the script that merge and again redirect merge to remove Repetitions and that at the end redirect again to sort script. Is it the easiest way to do that ?